Passing parameter from front-end to Controller in Spring boot
I am creating a Spring boot application for booking flights. I have a home page, where flight details are displayed in a table using thymeleaf as below:
<table border="solid">
    <tr>
        <th>Airline</th>
        <th>Flight Number</th>
        <th>Departure</th>
        <th>Arrival</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Seats available</th>
        <th>Price</th>  
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="flight : ${flightList}">
        <td th:text="${flight.airlineName}"></td>
        <td th:text="${flight.flightNumber}" th:field="*{flightNumber}"></td>
        <td th:text="${flight.departure}"></td>
        <td th:text="${flight.arrival}"></td>
        <td th:text="${flight.date}"></td>
        <td th:text="${flight.availableSeats}"></td>
        <td th:text="${flight.price}"></td> 
    </tr>
</table>

Below is the controller:
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/booking")
public class BookingController {
    
    @Autowired
    private FlightService flightService;

    @GetMapping("/booking-page")
    public String getBookingPage(@RequestParam("flightNumber") String flightNumber) {
        flightService.findFlightByFlightNumber(flightNumber);
        return "bookFlight";
    }
}

I am trying to fetch the specific flight using the flight number (when the specific row is clicked) and pass it as parameter to the controller in order to display it on the next page.
It is not working though. Any alternative?

You need to pass a Model into the controller and add attributes: model.addAttribute("flight", flight);

Thymeleaf needs a model to read data from. Currently you are not passing it any data anywhere.
Here's how you can use a Model:
@GetMapping("/booking-page")
public String getBookingPage(@RequestParam("flightNumber") String flightNumber, Model model) {
    Flight flight = flightService.findFlightByFlightNumber(flightNumber);
    model.addAttribute("flight", flight);
    return "bookFlight";
}

Alternatively, you can use @ModelAttribute to directly return the flight object as a model attribute:
@GetMapping("/booking-page")
public String getBookingPage(@RequestParam("flightNumber") String flightNumber, @ModelAttribute("flight") Flight flight) {
    flight = flightService.findFlightByFlightNumber(flightNumber);
    return "bookFlight";
}


You can use an anchor tag (<a>) within each table row to create a clickable element that directs the user to the path with the flight number as a request parameter.


<table border="solid">
  <tr>
    <th>Airline</th>
    <th>Flight Number</th>
    <th>Departure</th>
    <th>Arrival</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Seats available</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr th:each="flight : ${flightList}">
    <td th:text="${flight.airlineName}"></td>
    <td>
      <a th:href="@{'/booking/booking-page' + '?flightNumber=' + ${flight.flightNumber}}" th:text="${flight.flightNumber}"> </a>
    </td>
    <td th:text="${flight.departure}"></td>
    <td th:text="${flight.arrival}"></td>
    <td th:text="${flight.date}"></td>
    <td th:text="${flight.availableSeats}"></td>
    <td th:text="${flight.price}"></td>
  </tr>
</table>



